# Woocommerce button not aligned to center

Tags: html, wordpress, css, woocommerce

My Site is [**DELIVERY**](http://constantin-entertainment.info/deliveryservice/product-category/eatbles/) . i was styling the appaerance of each products.i made the product image and price to the center of the div using

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images img, .woocommerce div.product div.images img, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images img, .woocommerce-page div.product div.images img,.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product a img
{width:50% !important;
margin :0 auto !important;}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product     .price,.woocommerce ul.products li.product h3, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product h3
{text-align:center;}
```

and when i tried making the cart button at center it is not actualy moving.

i tried

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product a
{margin:0 auto;text-align:center;}
```

but nothing worked.Plaese help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` to the `<li>` container of the product.

```
ul.products li{
    text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following on your cart button, also make sure its parent container has a width set.

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
products li{
    text-align: center
}
```

and

```
margin:0 auto;
```